# Why is OnFragmentInteractionListener returning null in onCreatView()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I´ve searched online but can´t find the solution. This code is taken from a dialog fragment. When I click the done button a null pointer exception for `mListner(OnFragmentInteraction`, interface) is thrown. How do I prevent this from happening or what am I doing wrong. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_over_dialog, container, false);
        TextView rWins = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numWinTV);
        TextView rLose = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numLoseTV);
        TextView rounds = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numRoundsTV);
        TextView name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playerNameHeadingTV);
        getDialog().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.game_over));
        if (p1RoundWins != p2RoundWins)
            winnersName = "" + getArguments().getString(Constant.PLAYER_NAME);
        else {
            winnersName = getResources().getString(R.string.draw);
            TextView wins = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.winTV);
            wins.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        Button doneB = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        doneB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.gameWinner(winnersName);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `mListener`?

Comment: It's initialized in on attach. It's the default place for it when you auto insert. It's also a global variable.

Comment: You have to post more code, so that people can help you.